# How to listen to a TCP stream on my FastAPI server

Tags: python, while-loop, fastapi, zeromq, pyzmq

I am working on a project building an API that is able to send the live location of vehicles to a frontend.

I get this location data by subscribing to a ZMQ stream by running a while loop. This is all working and if I just run my stream as a script I can print all kinds of information to the terminal (I'll store those in a database later on).

I also have the FastAPI server up and running

Now what I'd like to do is:

- At startup start the server so I can make API calls
- Start the while loop and start receiving data from the ZMQ stream

What happens instead:

- It seems either / or.
- I can import a function with the while loop but this blocks the server from starting up
- Or I can run the server with no means to start the stream

Here is my code:

```
# General FastAPI Imports
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request
from data_collection.livestream import enable_data_stream
from client_service import client_api

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(client_api.router, prefix="/API/V1")
@app.get('/')
def read_root(request: Request):
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

The Stream:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from io import BytesIO
import zmq
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET




context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect("tcp://SERVER")
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE)

while True:
    multipart = subscriber.recv_multipart()
    address = multipart[0]
    try:
        contents = GzipFile('', 'r', 0, BytesIO(multipart[1])).read()
        root = ET.fromstring(contents)
        print("Updates Received:")
        # Gets the timestamp
        print('time', root[3].text)
        print('X Coord: ', root[4][0][12].text)
        print('Y Coord: ', root[4][0][13].text)
```

I tried looking into the multiprocess and threading implementations for python but I'm unsure how those tie in with starting the FastAPI process (as that's enabled from Uvicorn)

Comment: You could split out your stream as a worker process. I'll see if I can create an example and post it below.

Comment: I would recommend looking into [PyZMQ's async API](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/eventloop.html#asyncio), which should play nice with FastAPI's async nature. I would create an async task on startup using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) and have that task write to e.g. a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the example below, the server and worker are started in separate processes because the While loop won't resolve. It seems that you were on the right track. In my example, I have these functions in one file, but there are no restrictions on someone breaking them out into their own files:

```py
import uvicorn
import multiprocessing
import time
import zmq
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from gzip import GzipFile
from io import BytesIO
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


def server():
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)


def worker():
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    subscriber.connect("tcp://SERVER")
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE)

    while True:
        multipart = subscriber.recv_multipart()
        address = multipart[0]

        try:
            contents = GzipFile('', 'r', 0, BytesIO(multipart[1])).read()
            root = ET.fromstring(contents)
            print("Updates Received:")
            # Gets the timestamp
            print('time', root[3].text)
            print('X Coord: ', root[4][0][12].text)
            print('Y Coord: ', root[4][0][13].text)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Error: %s" % multipart[1])
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Runs server and worker in separate processes
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=server)
    p1.start()

    time.sleep(1)  # Wait for server to start

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks champ! Really nice this worked for me. I should call the main.py script directly then, not run the uvicorn app:main on startup.

Comment: Yup uvicorn is for the ASGI web server. This approach offloads everything else

Comment: what's the point if you can't use socket data inside any of fastapi function?